# How to provide parameters fig.show(config=A, post_script=B) versus dcc.Graph(figure=fig)

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Using

```
fig.show(config=configFigures, post_script=[js])
```

I can configure my Figure (candlesticks and scatterplots) and also perform actions using the post_script parameter.
This works fine at mine but I don't know how to provide the config and postscript parameters if I want to use

```
dcc.Graph(figure= fig)
```

How can I provide those parameters while calling dcc.Graph or how can I provide that info to the figure before I use dcc.Graph?